# Raspberry Pi 3B USB Over-current Condition

Tags: pi-3

How does Raspberry Pi 3B USB protects from over-current condition? What specific device is used to determine such condition?

Comment: Are you referring to the polyfuse? Why are you concerned about over current?

Comment: Yes, because I want to know when such condition happens. At what level of current it will declare overcurrent.

Comment: I have a device consuming 450mA of current and then Raspberry Pi OS declares it as overcurrent. Is it every USB 2.0 port should allow 500mA?

Comment: What is an "over-current condition"?

Comment: @Milliways that's what I need to find out because dmesg log is showing it.

Comment: [ 63251.323456] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #3